# How to make a VirtualBox VM that shares harddrive with host safely?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I just want to make a Virtual Machine to run Minecraft without GPU hardware acceleration.

Is there a way to make a Virtual Machine that shares the same filesystem as my MacBook currently has? Even better if it has the same Operating System so I don't need to redownload it then install it on the VM.

Comment: It's possible to turn an installed OS into a VM but it's messy and unless you have a good reason to do it better avoid. What you want to do, however, isn't possible.

Comment: So you want to essentially run a copy of your current computer as a VM, so you can have precisely the same software/settings but virtualize hardware? Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Not that they do what you ask, but Shared Folders are a thing in basically all VM software.

Comment: Even if you run a tool to copy your physical installation to a virtual HDD.  You are NOT going to bypass the requirement for hardware acceleration that I can guarantee Minecraft client has, the fact you likely have Apple silicon, makes this a very complicate problem you want to solve. Running a Minecraft server might be possible, but you certainly, are better of running a virtual machine running an OS for that purpose.  Attaching a physical partition to a VM is possible.  But have not given us vey much to go off of.

Comment: @music2myear I think so

Comment: @Ramhound I have an old intel macbook, and I've heard Minecraft apparently doesn't require hardware acceleration (because lwjgl doesn't)

Comment: @theonlygusti - You don’t mention which version of Minecraft but modern versions absolutely require hardware acceleration, which means either OpenGL, DX, or Vulkan. Vulkan and DX 12 are more difficult if not impossible on VMs

Comment: @Ramhound how do you know that modern versions require hardware acceleration?

Comment: @theonlygusti - I am familiar with Minecraft. I have tracked most of its graphical improvements it has received over the years. I see no evidence lwjgl would not require hardware acceleration due its OpenGL support.

Comment: Ok, what you ask is impossible. But, you're not asking the real question you have. Take a few steps back and ask the real question: how do you run Minecraft without GPU acceleration. THAT question may have a positive answer. There may be a lot of "why", but tell us why and ask THAT question and you may have better success.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine is probably not the right solution for what you're
trying to do.
A better solution might be to use
[Docker](https://www.docker.com/),
which can be described as a light-weight virtual environment
working on top of your OS.

You may either use a ready-made docker image such as
[itzg/minecraft-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/itzg/minecraft-server),
or create your own image.
For the latter, see
[Setting Up a Minecraft Server Using Docker – Part 1](https://www.docker.com/blog/minecraft-server-docker-1/).

Whatever you decide, Docker will require some study in order to use it
effectively.

Comment: I want to run the minecraft client (not server) without letting it use hardware acceleration

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/r/acaranta/docker-minecraft-client